# iPhone app - keeps track of the number of sms sent from the app user's phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am looking to develop an iPhone app which keeps track of the number of sms sent from the app user's phone. So, is that possible for me to fetch the number of sms's sent from user's iPhone and to show in the app which I am gonna develop?

I guess, its tricky for you. But, if you know anything abt this, kindly let me know too.
Your response will be helpful for me.
Thanks in advance. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

Without jail breaking the device, you cannot retrieve this information.

Comment: The answer given is really clear, you cant fetch that information without jailbreaking your device. Even is you do manage to get that info apple will reject your app for using private apis.